# Why might I not see stty key changes reflected in "stty -a"

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, fish, konsole, stty

I'm trying to change some key bindings in my console (Konsole). If I map intr to Ctrl-k, by running

```
stty intr \^k
```

I don't see the change reflected in

```
stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 46; columns 172; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Why would this be?

<strike>Note the Ctrl-K IS working to send an interrupt.</strike> Ctrl-C continues to work to send an interrupt. If I try unmapping Ctrl-C by running

```
stty intr ^-
```

or

```
stty intr undef
```

It does not get undefined, and stty -a still shows exactly as it did before, with "intr = ^C;"

---

**Update:** I now suspect it has something to do with the shell I'm running (fish). In another Konsole tab where I'm using a different profile so that I'm using bash, I'm getting the expected behavior.

Comment: Which Linux version? I cannot reproduce it on Ubuntu on Windows.

Comment: @harrymc This Chakra linux which is derived from Arch.

Comment: Compare `stty intr \^k; stty -a`. The commands themselves work. Your hypothesis about fish seems right. It probably "fixes" the terminal around the time it prints prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been broken forever. See

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2315

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/814

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1041

And several others. The workaround is to use bash, zsh, ksh, or sh to run the `stty` command then do `exec fish`.